# How to accelerate PHP execution by using cached result?

Tags: php, caching, nginx, opcache

I'm using PHP-FPM 5.6 version.

php -v shows there's OPcache in place.

I have a PHP script that's accepting parameters and giving me same `2.2k` HTML output all the time.

The script execution does not involve any connectivity to MySQL.

In Chrome Developer Tools, I'm seeing an execution time of `900ms`.

I find that this is relatively slow.

I would like to shorten this execution time.

Given that OPcache is in place with this version of PHP, can I use it to cache the result of my PHP script execution for a faster response time?

Or if there's an alternative approach?

Any configuration to be tweaked in `php.ini`, `/etc/php.d/10-opcache.ini` or `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`?

And how do I purge the cached result when needed?

Comment: From the manual: "OPcache improves PHP performance by storing precompiled script bytecode in shared memory, thereby removing the need for PHP to load and parse scripts on each request.". In other words, it does not cache bytecode execution output. See: http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php You need to use something else. Slow execution might also be a result of a slow connection, better measure execution time on the server itself. A faster server could also help. :-)

Comment: before you go crazy configuring to death, verify what is happening server side. With Apache (sorry i know skwat bout nginx), i load mod_log_config, and set the LogFormat to `LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %T/%D I:%I O:%O"  common`. This yields something like `127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jun/2016:15:19:05 -0400] "POST /system/cron/do.php HTTP/1.1" 200 197 0/10786 I:331 O:425` , i.e. that particular request took a whole 10.8 ms to run. You want to compare that number to your 990 ms.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg makes sense. Is there a LogFormat equivalent for `nginx`?

Comment: @KDX well, as i confessed i know very little about nginx. But google reveals **[this interesting article](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-logging-for-application-performance-monitoring/)**. It may help you dissect that 990 ms into meaningful times (http call setup/teardown, php initialization). I also log time 'between first line of code and last' in any API servlet. The above took 1.8 ms 'in code', so i can infer the php-fpm call setup and teardown too.

Answer (score 3):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but it might be useful. The way to measure execution time could involve these two functions:

```
function getMicroTime()
// return time in whole seconds with microseconds
{
   return microtime(TRUE);
}


function getUserTime()
// this clock only runs when we have CPU cycles, so it runs slower that the normal clock
// use this to accurately time the excution time of scripts instead of the above function
{
  $usage = getrusage();
  return $usage["ru_utime.tv_sec"]+0.000001*$usage["ru_utime.tv_usec"];
}
```

At the beginning of your script you store the start times:

```
$startMicroTime = getMicroTime();
$startUserTime  = getUserTime();
```

So that at the end you can echo the execution time:

```
echo 'Full time = '.round(1000*(getMicroTime()-$startMicroTime),2).' ms<br>';
echo 'User time = '.round(1000*(getUserTime()-$startUserTime),2).' ms<br>';
```

Again, this doesn't answer your question, but it could be useful. Ok, to make this a valid answer, have a read here:

https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/output-caching-for-beginners/

Comment: Follow up your earlier comment, the server I'm using is a fresh VPS with Wordpress installed for staging/testing purpose.  Currently no traffic and should have full resource available.  I use W3 Total Cache + Memcached for serving the cached front page from the memory.  On `Chrome Developer Tools` it shows `85 ms`.  Thus the execution of a simple PHP script with static HTML output and no MySQL connectivity, as I mentioned above, giving me over `900ms`, is not something I'm expecting.  Is there a `bytecode execution output` caching solution that I can add on top of `OPcache`?

Comment: The article is interesting, but I'm not intending to implement my own caching solution from scratch, but looking for a way of integration using existing tools out there.

Comment: I've heard that mencached is used for this: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.memcached.php but I have no experience with it myself.

Comment: I do use `memcached` module with `W3 Totcal Cache + Wordpress` integration.  That's why I'm getting the `85ms` for my Wordpress front page.  But the PHP I'm working on is not residing on of the Wordpress framework. Thus I'm looking for a cache solution for the PHP output result.  I'll have a further look at the URL you sent me. Thanks.

Comment: It basically also means you need to write some code. For example: https://www.script-tutorials.com/how-to-use-memcache-with-php/ BTW, in 900ms, on a good server, you must be executing a huge amount of PHP scripts. On my server, with MySQL connection and no caching, I easily achieve an execution time between 40 - 80 ms with quite complex scripts.

Comment: Good read. Seems straight forward for implement. I'm also looking at Nginx FastCGI Cache and Varnish as alternative solution.  I prefer doing minimum modification of the PHP code itself for easier upgrade in the future.  I rather on on the optimizing the environment.  The slow execution of the code I'm having is mainly due to calling external `curl` to get remote content, thus I figure that caching the result would be the most economic way to solving the problem.  No need to invoke `curl` to fetch same content over and over again.

Comment: Ah, yes, fetching external content can be slow. Using a very simple caching mechanism for that, only needing a few lines of code, can speed things up quite a lot.

Comment: I ended up using FastCGI Cache as a solution as Varnish might not be working over HTTPS.  It comes with purge mechanism too.  It does require compiling nginx from source to include the purge module.